# Fastest and minimal random access data structure in Java

Tags: java

I have written up a data structure in Java that supports the following features:

- `get(i)`
- `set(i, e)`
- `add(e)`
- `remove(e)`
- `contains(e)`
- `size`

Elements must remain in order and iteration needs to be as fast as possible. The code does not require thread safety.

I am looking for ways to improve the speed further. It is critical to reduce times to as small as possible because this code will be invoked hundreds of thousands of times per second. I believe it's possible to optimize my `stream()` method!

This is my current solution which seems to work:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public final class Indexer<E> implements Iterable<E> {

    private final int minIndex;
    private final Object[] arr;

    private int size = 0;
    private int highest;

    public Indexer(int minIndex, int capacity) {
        this.minIndex = highest = minIndex;
        arr = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public Indexer(int capacity) {
        this(0, capacity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E get(int index) {
        return (E) arr[index];
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        Object last = arr[index];
        arr[index] = element;
        if (last == null && element != null) {
            size++;
            if (highest < index)
                highest = index;
        } else if (last != null && element == null) {
            size--;
            if (highest == index)
                highest--;
        }
        return (E) last;
    }

    public int add(E element) {
        int index = nextIndex();
        set(index, element);
        return index;
    }

    public void remove(E element) {
        for (int i = minIndex; i <= highest; i++) {
            if (element == arr[i]) {
                set(i, null);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(E element) {
        for (E e : this) {
            if (element == e)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public int nextIndex() {
        for (int i = minIndex; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (null == arr[i])
                return i;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Out of indices!");
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {

            private int pointer = minIndex;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return size > 0 && pointer <= highest;
            }

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public E next() {
                return (E) arr[pointer++];
            }

        };
    }

    public Stream<E> stream() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
    }

}
```

Comment: One quick and easy change is to change all of your operations with "--" to "+= -1". This works because it is easier for computers to perform addition than subtraction on the architecture level. If you are calling many thousands of times per second, you'll notice an improvement.

Comment: @EvanBechtol You'll want to check that the Java compiler doesn't already do that automatically, and that it doesn't convert `+= -1` to `-= 1` or just `--`. Remember that the JIT does a lot of things very well, including squeeze every bit of speed out of the program once it's called enough.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Good point, I honestly haven't checked whether or not this is done behind-the-scenes already :)

Comment: What does "Elements must remain in order" mean?  Because if you add `1 2 3 4 5`, then remove `3`, then add `6`, currently your order becomes `1 2 6 4 5`.  Is that intended?  Also, can you explain the purpose of `minIndex`?  In what situation would you create an `Indexer` with a `minIndex` that is not 0?  Lastly, which operations will be performed hundreds of thousands of times per second?  Is it `add`, `remove`, `contains`, `get`, or iterating?

Comment: @JS1 Yes that is intended. The elements must keep the same index. My use of `minIndex` is to start from index 1 because the dependent code requires that. I don't know if it's better to remove `minIndex` and just add 1 to the index in that case (and subtract one when getting).

Comment: @Jire If performance is critical, then whoop out your profiler and measure where the time is consumed. It is the only way to go about it, measure before and after to see if your changes actually improved your code or made it worse. [But be aware of the caveats of writing benchmarks in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Comment: @Jire this is pretty much a simple implementation of [ArrayList<T>](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) without automatic resizing. What is the use case that keeps you from using the standard Java implementation?

Comment: @OliverS there must be a direct map from index to object and it must keep track of highest index (in some way) to make iteration fast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Speed concerns

Many of your operations are \$O(n)\$ and could be made faster.  You didn't say which operations were the most commonly used operations, so I'm not sure if you care about the following.

**add(), nextIndex()**

These are both \$O(n)\$ operations, because they both need to search the array for a free slot.  If you kept a set or list of free slots, this could be faster.  To retain the behavior that the lowest numbered free slot is used next, you need to use an ordered set/list.  So for example, if you used a `TreeSet` to track your free slots, you could have \$O(\log n)\$ adds.

**remove(), contains()**

These are both currently \$O(n)\$, because you search the array for the element.  You could make these \$O(1)\$ by keeping a `HashMap` of elements mapped to indices, for elements added to the array.

### MinIndex and capacity

I don't like the way that `minIndex` and `capacity` are used.  If I create an `Indexer` with `minIndex=100` and `capacity=100`, I would expect that I could use indices `[100..199]`.  But in the current implementation, I get a useless `Indexer` with no usable slots.  Right now, `capacity` acts more like a `maxIndex` so it is somewhat misnamed.  Another thing is that if `minIndex` is not 0, you are currently allocating an array where some of the slots will never be used.

If the `minIndex` concept is to be kept, I would suggest that the `Indexer` support indices in the range `[minIndex .. minIndex+capacity-1]`.  You should then allocate an array of size `capacity`, and then subtract `minIndex` from your index whenever you access the array.

Then again, if `minIndex` is only ever going to be 1, it would be faster to just keep your code as is.  But you should probably allocate an array of size `minIndex+capacity` instead of just `capacity`, or else document what `capacity` actually means.

Comment: Iteration is the most used operation but `add` and `contains` are common as well.

Comment: Might be worth noting that your suggestions to use `TreeSet` and `HashMap` will probably reduce performance somewhat for small \$n\$ due to a larger constant factor (cache misses in a tree structure, and all that...).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your solutions will help me in the future but in this case I am not concerned about add or contains performance. My #1 concern (which is what's being used so much) is iteration. Iteration needs to be as fast as possible which means I need to track the highest index. During iteration I would actually prefer not to deal with null.

Comment: @Jire How big is your typical array and how many nulls do you normally have in the array?  There are ways you could skip over the nulls quickly during iteration, but it would cause your `add` and `remove` functions to be slower.  But if there are very few nulls, you might want to just have your `next()` function skip over any null entries.

Comment: @JS1 Typically 2000-10000, typically half nulls or more.

Comment: @Jire At that size with around 50% nulls, it's probably best to keep doing what you are doing.  If you don't use the null values when you iterate, you could have your iterator's `next()` function skip over null entries in the array.  On average you only have to skip 1 entry before returning a valid entry.  That would be faster than setting up a complicated system to look up the next non-null entry in constant time.

Answer (score 10):

Wow, this is pretty nice code. I've only got a few little nitpicks.

*NB: I have not benchmarked the code before and after making these changes. If you'd like, I can, but as of right now, these are untested changes.*

*NB2: Most of these are just conforming to convention, since after a bit of research I've discovered that the JIT makes things scary fast after a few thousand iterations by putting in every optimization I'd never think of.*

1. In `remove(E)` and `contains(E)`, you compare equality with `==` instead of `equals`. This is a bad idea, because sometimes people want to specify their way of comparing objects. If they don't, this will default to `Object`'s implementation, which is just `==`. The exception, of course, is when you're dealing with either primitives or `null`, but you don't have to worry about that, since you can't use primitive types as `E`, and their class equivalents all define `equals` appropriately.
2. It's standard for `remove` to return the element it just removed, so you'll want to change the internals of the `for` a little bit:

   ```
   if (element.equals(arr[i])) {
       set(i, null);
       return element;
   }
   ```

   and change the method signature to match.
3. I'd recommend adding a `remove(int)` as well, which does basically the same thing as `remove(E)` but doesn't have to loop through. It would look something like this:

   ```
   public E remove(int index) {
       E ret = get(index);
       set(index, null);
       return ret;
   }
   ```
4. Continuing with the trend of "I think your methods are bad and here's how I think you should do them instead", I think your lack of `indexOf` is bad and here's how I think you could implement it:

   ```
   public int indexOf(E element) {
       for (int i = minIndex; i < size; i++) {
           if (element.equals(arr[i]))
               return i;
       }
       return -1;
   }
   ```
5. In `set(int, E)` I'd recommend renaming `last` to `original`, or it might be confused with the last element of the array.
6. In `iterator()`'s anonymous class's `next()`, you should add a check to make sure that you're not overstepping the array's bounds, even if all you end up doing is throwing a different error. [corsiKa suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95113/fastest-and-minimal-random-access-data-structure-in-java/95119?noredirect=1#comment173637_95119) using an `IllegalStateException`, which makes a good bit of sense. The most important thing is that, from the name of the exception alone, you can figure out roughly what went wrong, though not necessarily the details.

That's about it! Well-written code all. If you give me some test cases, I can benchmark the version with my tips and the version without.

Comment: No explanation for the random downvote on a year-old answer? That's odd.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about the use of `minIndex`. Let's say I create an instance `new Indexer<E>(5,20);` it implies that the indexes `0,1,2,3,4` will never be used? Therefore it seems like a useless use of memory, though I might misunderstand what you're achieving with this. If it is the case, consider that your code might use comments in order to explain why you use the `minIndex`!

There's a bug with the `minIndex` too. You check for this index when you `add` and `remove` from your data structure but not when you set. Meaning that if I wanted, I could do this :

```
Indexer<Integer> indexer = new Indexer<>(2,5);
indexer.set(0,2);
//My value wasn't removed because it's index is before the minIndex
indexer.remove(2);
```

In the `set` method, the variable name `last` is confusing, I thought it implied the last value of your `Object[]`. I think naming it `previous` might be better. Also, it is confusing as why your `set` returns the previous value. You should comment your methods to explain what they do and what they return. Because in this case I might think it would return the new value. The same problem applies to your `add` method, it isn't intuitive to understand that the `int` returned is the new index. Comments should make this a lot clearer :)

You should use `equals` over `==` in your comparisons. `==` compared the reference value whereas `equals` will compare using the `equals` override of the type you are using, which leads to less errors.

What happens if I have multiple times the same element. Is it intended that you remove only the first instance that is found?

Comment: I was writing my answer when @QPaysTaxes posted his, so some points might be similar..

Comment: Aw, dang, I missed the `minIndex` bug! No fair.

Comment: That'll learn you to post your answer before mine! ;)

Answer (score 3):

If memory is not a concern, use a combination of a `HashMap` and a custom linked list.

Use a variable to store the current size of the linked list.

For `add()` do the following:

- Append the item to the list.
- Put the item to the `HashMap`.
- Increase size variable.

For `set()`:

- Just replace the item in the list and `HashMap`.

For `remove()`:

- Get list object via `HashMap`, connect the previous and next items via their linked references.
- Now call `remove()` on the `HashMap`.
- Decrease the size variable.

For `iterate->next()`:

- Just traverse the linked list.

For `contains()`:

- Simply check the `HashMap`.

For `size()`:

- Return the internal size variable.

If memory is a concern and a little less speed is okay, use a `HashArrayMappedTrie` instead of a simple `HashMap`.

The above implementation gives a time complexity of \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ for all operations except iteration, which is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ for full traversal.

Comment: This is the right answer. This is a reinventing the wheel problem and you provided one of the best answer that I know.

Comment: @rdllopes thanks, i appreciate that. this was actually my first ever post on stackexchange.